# How to insert rows with foreign keys using GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

**Defined models**

```
package models

import (
    "time"

    _ "gorm.io/gorm"
)



type User struct {
    UserID    uint   `gorm:"primarykey " json:"user_id"`
    Username  string `gorm:"unique" json:"username "` // gorm:"unique" makes it so that you can't have the same username twice
    CreatedAt time.Time
    Articles  []Article `gorm:"foreignKey:ArticleID"`
}

type Article struct {
    ArticleID    uint   `gorm:"primarykey " json:"article_id"`
    User         User   `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL; foreignkey:UserID; association_foreignkey:UserID"`
    ArticleTitle string `json:"article_title"`
    ArticleBody  string `json:"article_body"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time
}
```

**Defined view to insert a single new Article**

```
package views

import (
    "fiber_server/database"
    "fiber_server/models"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

type User models.User
type Article models.Article

func CreateTestingArticles(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    db, err := database.GetDBConn()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.Create(&User{
        UserID:   1,
        Articles: Article{ArticleTitle: "my_first_article", ArticleBody: "body"},
    })

    return c.SendString("articles created!")

}
```

The view thing throws an error, saying that i `cannot use (Article literal) (value of type Article) as []models.Article value in struct literal`

How can i insert a new row with a foreign key relationship to the User model in this case?
And do i need to use the User model to create the article, or is it better to do it by using only the Article model? *talking about changing the `db.Create(&User` thing*

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You just need change to

```golang
    db.Create(&model.User{
        UserID: 1,
        Articles: []model.Article{
            {ArticleTitle: "my_first_article", ArticleBody: "body"},
        },
    })
```

And don't use new types `User` and `Article` instead of `model.User` and `model.Article`, [see example](https://play.golang.org/p/j1ROkaxS9m5), also read [Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Properties_of_types_and_values)

What about insert row, I don't work with `gorm`, but i guess [this](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Append-Associations) will help.
Maybe it should look like this:

```golang
db.Model(&model.User{UserID: 1}).Association("Articles").Append(&model.Article{ArticleTitle: "my_first_article", ArticleBody: "body"})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Strange, something didn't quite work. Tested and changed the handler thing to both of the recommendations. `func CreateArticle(c *fiber.Ctx) error {

 db, err := database.GetDBConn()
 if err != nil {
  panic(err)
 }

 db.Create(&models.User{
  UserID:   1,
  Username: "bob",
  Articles: []models.Article{
   {ArticleTitle: "test-test-test", ArticleBody: "test-test-test"},
  },
 })

 return c.SendString("article for userId 1 created!")

}` didn't work. The last one also dind't. Will post a solved case once i figure this thing out.

Comment: Try embed `gorm.Model` into your models. `type User struct { gorm.Model ... }`

Comment: Created a link to the thing. https://play.golang.org/p/e4pnlMn2KS-